# authenticating to tinder via curl

Tags: facebook, curl, network-programming, tinder

I have been reading multiple articles on how to sniff and subsequently use the data obtained to interact with closed source apis recently.

I am concentrated on the tinder api since it seemed to me ample research had been done already on it, hence it would be easy to learn from.

http://ttcubicle.blogspot.com/2015/03/reverse-engineering-tinders-api.html
http://ec2-52-42-144-243.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/tinder/

Althrough I managed to sniff the authentification between the tinder app on my phone and the server through fiddler, I am not able to actually simulate that login using curl on the command line

----- Below is the request send from my phone to the server --- for obvious reasons I changed my actual data ----

```
POST https://api.gotinder.com/auth HTTP/1.1
platform: android
User-Agent: Tinder Android Version 6.5.1
os-version: 23
Facebook-ID: 10151935000326599
Accept-Language: en
app-version: 1955
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 257
Host: api.gotinder.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
X-Auth-Token: ccXX9a-4a99c-4e32-8154-9b21asf5eec

{"facebook_token":"EAfasfasfasfN6solZAh8M3kwxsP1JzF6OBDocdNUEyxd8tsVCN6kWZA6fArZB0T5dZArmdVvKAXUuQZCOtoVZBPasfzUMz9RfFoSpEifEVm7bAIspEerbLKRgW3DCpHHuxVyZApr1koAHhIjCGtxUZAAZAtDvTTbayrkF","facebook_id":"111111119","locale":"en"}
```

My knowledge regarding POST / Headers and all of these things is still a bit shacky (thats why I am trying to re-enact) but from what I understand that next step should be to send a POST request with curl that sends the X-Auth-Token in the header and facebook_token and so on in the data part.

something like this:

```
curl  -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-Auth-Token: cc5555a-499c-4e32-8154-9b25555ec" -d '{"facebook_token":"EAAGasdpsBAEzbJDJdcHXLjKpDjN6solZAh8M3kwxsP1JzF6OBDocdNUEyxd8tsVCN6kWZA6fArZB0T5dZArmdVvKAXUuQZCOtoVZBPZBMTUJzUMz9RfFoSpEifEVm7bAIspEerbLKRgW3DCpHHuxVyZApr1koAHhIjCGtxUZAAZA555TTbayrkF","facebook_id":"101519555326599","locale":"en"}' https://api.gotinder.com/auth
```

However, no matter how I change the parameters around, I always get Errorcodes 500 or 401 thrown back at me. The maximum I can get is the server telling me that it excpects a facebook_token (which is obviously send in the data section)

Does anyone has experience with this sort of problem ?

Thank you

Comment: is that even allowed?

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: what i mean is, i am pretty sure tinder does not allow that. or is that an official api?

Comment: ehm ok... DISCLAIMER  - FOR EDUCATIONAL PURPOSE ONLY

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered phyton and... holyshit i am in love!

```
  payloadauth = {"facebook_token":"EAA xxxxxx
  header1  = { 'platform': 'android','User-Agent': 'Tinder, 'X-Auth-Token':'cblabla


  with requests.Session() as c:
   response = c.post('https://api.gotinder.com/auth',data=payloadauth) 
   response = c.get('https://api.gotinder.com/recs/core?locale=en', headers=header1)
   print(response.json())
```

four lines of code...